# combine two image and change one of this on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to combine two images as in the diagram (under this message). The green image must be on the red line of another image, the problem is that by reducing the window as soon as the image 1 is resized responsively, the green image moves and no longer remains glued with the other. 
I reserve a way to do this (HTML, CSS or jQuery), the two images must behave as if they were one, responsively. Also when I click on the small image this must be changed with another image of the same size but different. 
Thanks to everyone who will offer me help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code snippet below (also found [here](https://codepen.io/z-smith/pen/QZxvXB) - it doesn't show very well on SO as you can't resize the output window).  It's not 100% clear to me what you want to do, but I think this accomplishes it. If not, let me know and I'll amend the answer.

```js
// This position is relative to the original size of the first image.
// i.e. when the window is exactly as large as image 1, image 2 will
// be displayed at (100, 200)
var pos = [100, 200];

// Reposition img2 as the window is resized
function reposition () {
  img2.style.left = (pos[0] / img1.naturalWidth * img1.clientWidth) + "px";
  img2.style.top = (pos[1] / img1.naturalHeight * img1.clientHeight) + "px";
  // The position is re-calculated based on the scaling of image 1
  // (its current width / its original width)
  // This is multiplied by pos to ensure that image 2 is always in the
  // same position proportional to the size of image 1
}

// Run reposition on window changes
window.onresize = function () {
  reposition();
}
window.onload = function () {
  reposition();
}

// Change the image on click
img2.onclick = function () {
  img2.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Unterf%C3%BChrung_B22_M%C3%BCnchner_Ring_3150017.jpg/320px-Unterf%C3%BChrung_B22_M%C3%BCnchner_Ring_3150017.jpg"
}
```

```css
/* Image 1 will fill the window */
#img1 {
  width: 50vw;
}

/* Image 2 has absolute position, and is 1/5 the size of image 1 */
#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15vw;
  /* Obviously this sizing can be changed */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/*
Because both images scale with the window, they will keep
 the same size proportional to each other. This could also be done in Javascript if needed.
*/
```

```html
<!-- Example images -->
<img id="img1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_960_720.jpg" />
<img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Tunnel_Eierberge_Regional_Express_3300341.jpg/320px-Tunnel_Eierberge_Regional_Express_3300341.jpg" />
```

Comment: I had tried something similar, but the smaller image is in a different position when the big image becomes responsive. To be clear if I had to make the statuette of your image rest your arms on a second image this would not happen.

Comment: @Win_z I've just added "body { margin: 0 }" to the CSS. Previously, the slight margin affected the positioning slightly (I didn't notice before) as img2 was absolutely positioned but img1 was not. Does this change fix your problem?

Comment: from your codepen it seems that it is resolutive, I will let you know on Monday when I try it, as I have to do all this in a popup window